# Can I rewrite this SQL code to the querydsl one?

Tags: sql, querydsl

I have sql code that's counting number of the records in db for different predicates

```
    SELECT
    count(*) as total_count,
    count(notAided) as not_aided_count,
    count(chatAided) as chat_aided_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN aided_with IS NULL THEN 1 END notAided,
        CASE WHEN aided_with = 'CHAT' THEN 1 END chatAided
    FROM sessions
) sessions
```

Can I rewrite it with querydsl? I take a look to the CaseBuilder, but founded no idea how to use it in the select query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can write:

```java
query.select(
     QSession.session.id.count().as("total_count"),
     new CaseBuilder().when(QSession.session.aidedWith.isNotNull()).then(1).otherwise(Expressions.<Integer> nullExpression()).count().as("not_aided_count"),
     new CaseBuilder().when(QSession.session.aidedWith.eq("CHAT")).then(1).otherwise(Expressions.<Integer> nullExpression()).count().as("chat_aided_count")
)
```

Which would be equivalent to the SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    count(*) as total_count,
    count(CASE WHEN aided_with IS NULL THEN 1 END) as not_aided_count,
    count(CASE WHEN aided_with = 'CHAT' THEN 1 END) as chat_aided_count
FROM sessions
```